# How to replace a value of a json file in java

Tags: java

I need some help with replacing a line in a json file. I have attempted using the same method i use to replace a line in a text file with no success.

Basically the json file contains the following string:

```
  "id": "TEXT",
```

And i want to replace the `TEXT` with `HELLO`

How would i do this, also i have the `json_simple` library imported if that is of any use for this.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "same method" that you're using?  A JSON file **is** a text file, so the method (probably some version of `String.replace`) should still work!

Comment: Please show the full JSON file and some of your code as to what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using a JSON parser as someone suggested, you can do it simply with a regex :

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\s*?\"id\"\\s*?:\\s*?)\"TEXT\",", "$1\"HELLO\"");
```

If the "TEXT" string is an unique placeholder for your replacement, you could simply use String [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method, in this way :

```
str.replace("\"TEXT\"", "\"HELLO\"");
```

Comment: What if json file contains "someval":"\"id\":\"TEXT\"," ? Regexps are not suitable for json parsing in any way. Regex simply can't understand which context it is in.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot replace a value as such. Therefore, you need to remove it from the json and add it back.

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(); // Your jsonobject here, this is just a sample
js.remove("id"); // Since you want to replace the value associated with id, remove it
js.put("id", "HELLO"); // add the new value for id
```

Comment: You dont need to remote and can directly update: `js.remove("id");`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
>     "id": {
>         "type": "String",
>         "value": "TEXT" ...
> 
> JSONObject modifiedjson=new JSONObject();
> modifiedjson.put("type",childobject.get("type"));
> modifiedjson.put("id","HELLO");
```